Nanobind c++ extension. How can i convert bytes() in python to uint8_t* to c++?
I can only conver only 1 byte data to c++. But if i change uint8_t* to uint16_t it will ok.
TypeError: func(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. func(arg0: int, arg1: int, /) -> None
Invoked with types: int, int
C++ FILE:
#include <nanobind/nanobind.h>
#include <cstdint>
namespace nb = nanobind;

void func (const uint8_t* ptr, uint64_t size) {
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
}

NB_MODULE(my_ext, m) {
    m.def("func", &func, nb::rv_policy::reference);
}

Python FILE:
import my_ext
import ctypes
import sys

data = 255
data = data.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
data = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big')
my_ext.func(data, int(sys.getsizeof(data)))

CMakeLists
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15...3.27)
project(sp_project) 

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.18)
  set(DEV_MODULE Development)
else()
  set(DEV_MODULE Development.Module)
endif()

find_package(Python 3.8 COMPONENTS Interpreter ${DEV_MODULE} REQUIRED)

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release" "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

# Detect the installed nanobind package and import it into CMake
execute_process(
  COMMAND "${Python_EXECUTABLE}" -m nanobind --cmake_dir
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE OUTPUT_VARIABLE NB_DIR)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${NB_DIR}")
find_package(nanobind CONFIG REQUIRED)
nanobind_add_module(my_ext my_ext.cpp)


That to_bytes/from_bytes dance seems weird, why not just a single to_bytes? That said, do you really expect the result to be a C-style, NUL-terminated character string? Otherwise, passing it to a %s placeholder for printf() isn't going to work reliably. This is all very confusing.

Replace the uint8_t* with nanobind's "wrapper" bytes class documented here: https://nanobind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_core.html.  More information about "wrappers" is here: https://nanobind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exchanging.html
